# Identity of a commutative ring

Tags: ring-theory

so I was trying to prove that $$F = \{f: R \to R \mid f(x) = 0 \,\forall x\in D\}$$ D is a subset of R is a commutative ring with an identity. I was able to prove that it is a commutative ring and was able to show that it has an additive identity. However, I got stuck with multiplicative identity because I know that it has to be 1: R to 1. However, this would imply that it does not belong to F. I don't know if I am not interpreting it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Btw, addition is pointwise and multiplication is pointwise.

Comment: It only has to be $1$ where $x \not\in D$; it can be $0$ on $D$.

Comment: what is $R$?, do you mean $R$ is the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ or something

Comment: @Uncool yeah I am sorry I mean the set of all real numbers.

Answer (score 6):

If you consider the function $z: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $z(x) = 0$ if $x \in D$ and $z(x) = 1$ if $x \not \in D$ you should be able to show that $z$ is a multiplicative identity for $F$.

Note that the problem does not require $F$ to have the same multiplicative identity as some larger more "natural" set of functions (for example the set of all functions $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, with the usual operations), just that it have a multiplicative identity.

Note also that if the functions were required to be continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$ (or perhaps have other interesting properties in addition to being $0$ on $D$) this construction might not work. The pointwise operations do, as you point out, require the identity to take the value $1$ a lot of the time (namely at all points not in $D$), and the definition of $D$ requires the identity to take the value $0$ on $D$, so that's what the identity has to be if there is one.